# searching for which x-variables affect y the most when there is strong collinearity among the x-variables

Tags: regression, multicollinearity

I have a sample of 33 observations with 16 variables. My main goal is to find which (could be several) of these affect y the most. Y is an unwanted error in a system and the x variables are possible causes of the error. I'm not trying to predict the size of the error, I'm searching for what could cause the error.

I'm using linear regression. My python package informs me that there is strong collinearity among the variables. I have confirmed this by calculating the VIF-number and also the correlation matrix. It is hard though to select which one of the 16 variables should stay and which should be taken out.

I understand that the model can become worse when there is much dependency among the x-variables. But looking at the output, I get some variables where the coefficients seem statistically significant (p < 0.0001).

Can I trust these results or do they mean nothing since I know that I have such strong collinearity? Or can I say I get some results that I can use despite having such strong collinearity?

EDIT: here is the entire summary

```
                            OLS Regression Results
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       0.999
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.998
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     1236.
Date:                Wed, 27 Mar 2024   Prob (F-statistic):           1.66e-20
Time:                        13:33:31   Log-Likelihood:                -631.43
No. Observations:                  33   AIC:                             1299.
Df Residuals:                      15   BIC:                             1326.
Df Model:                          17
Covariance Type:            nonrobust
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const      -1.819e+07    2.9e+07     -0.628      0.539   -7.99e+07    4.36e+07
var1           1.2290      0.324      3.798      0.002       0.539       1.919
var2          -2.0098      0.783     -2.566      0.022      -3.679      -0.340
var3       -1.025e+08   4.93e+06    -20.799      0.000   -1.13e+08    -9.2e+07
var4       -1.417e+07   6.81e+05    -20.799      0.000   -1.56e+07   -1.27e+07
var5          44.9058     23.935      1.876      0.080      -6.111      95.923
var6         260.3578     55.994      4.650      0.000     141.009     379.706
var7         -96.4852     54.781     -1.761      0.099    -213.249      20.279
var8          -0.1740      0.067     -2.605      0.020      -0.316      -0.032
var9           1.1791      0.433      2.725      0.016       0.257       2.101
var10        -78.2956    109.225     -0.717      0.484    -311.104     154.513
var11       1.761e+07   8.47e+05     20.799      0.000    1.58e+07    1.94e+07
var12         -0.2442      0.140     -1.747      0.101      -0.542       0.054
var13         -1.8203      1.764     -1.032      0.319      -5.581       1.940
var14        270.5083     64.680      4.182      0.001     132.645     408.371
var15      -1.082e+10    5.2e+08    -20.799      0.000   -1.19e+10   -9.71e+09
var16          0.5362      0.409      1.310      0.210      -0.336       1.408
var17         -1.6539      0.443     -3.732      0.002      -2.599      -0.709
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                       12.818   Durbin-Watson:                   2.102
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.002   Jarque-Bera (JB):               13.772
Skew:                          -1.130   Prob(JB):                      0.00102
Kurtosis:                       5.215   Cond. No.                     1.17e+12
==============================================================================
```

Correlations with y:

```
var1    -0.00776
var2     0.09759
var3    -0.04291
var4     0.02430
var5     0.10228
var6    -0.02072
var7     0.16964
var8    -0.04696
var9     0.03744
var10    0.07167
var11    0.07712
var12   -0.04468
var13   -0.00141
var14    0.02511
var15    0.04644
var16    0.32774
var17   -0.01643
```

Comment: With 33 observations and 16 variables any model is going to overfit. Use theory to reduce the number of variables.

Comment: Most of those correlations are really weak, which doesn't rule out the predictors concerned having some relevance. Some of your coefficients have massive (absolute) values, which is a telltale sign of over-fitting.

Answer (score 6):

A major issue here is that you have only 33 observations but are throwing, it seems, every available predictor into the model. The problem of (multi)collinearity is therefore as much self-inflicted as inherent in the system.

There is no set number of predictors that is definitely excessive, but rules of thumb to have say 10 observations for each predictor expose your model as extreme in this regard. As a personal rule, I would be very wary of more than 3 or 4 predictors with that small a sample size.

You seem to have a black-and-white view of regression, lurching between optimism that it will identify causes and pessimism that you've fitted a useless model. Most experiences are in between. What counts as a cause must hinge also on subject-matter understanding of the underlying processes.

It is hard to say more about seeing any of the raw data. For example, the very high $R^2$ could be an artefact of strong outliers.

I would start very cautiously, looking at the individual correlations between each predictor and the response.

Comment: thank you for your reply. My english is not the best, but what I was trying to describe was the question whether the collinearity made the p-vales (which were very low) lower than they otherwise would have been? Or is it the other way around, the p-values in this case are low despite the collinearity? The thing you said about the high R2 value being an artefact sounds very interesting. I tried to google but I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: My point is that a model with so many predictors is not defensible. @Frank Harrell makes essentially the same point. Worrying about the details of inferential results is misplaced when the entire exercise is misconceived. You could work out which (say 4) predictors have the highest correlations with your response and show us the data for the response and those predictors. That would be manageable with such a small dataset.

Comment: I've tried to to exactly that but I don't know exactly how to do it. I've tried to add variables one by one and calculate the VIF. But when making a smaller selection I get a higher p-value on the beta-coefficients. I've studied this in the university but haven't used it so much. From what I recall, what usually happened when you had too many variables in a model was that the p-values became high and the p-values were lower when you removed some variables. In this case it seems to be the other way around? But that maybe because I'm not doing the selection in a smart way.

Comment: If you're unable or unwilling to show us some data, I can't add helpfully to my answer. The problem remains that you are _overfitting_. Otherwise this kind of conversation is like describing symptoms to a doctor or mechanic without letting them look for themselves.

Comment: I understand, I'm not sure my company would allow it. Sorry for that!

Comment: Can you show the correlations between the response and each individual predictor?

Answer (score 3):

I think it is always good practice to report what is going on, even if it is something 'considered bad' such as multicollinearity. Now, the impact of multicollinearity would mainly be on your standard errors; i.e. they would be inflated. If you think they are still reasonably small and valuable, you can report them and use the results. (The word 'small' should be used in comparison with your coefficients and in the light of your goals/research question.)

Note that a significant p-value is not always one-to-one related with only standard errors and multicollinearity. Sample size also plays a big role: however, since you have only 33 observations, this will not be something to break your head about right now.

Answer (score 3):

To amplify on Nick's answer, it will be very easy to demonstrate with the bootstrap that your sample size is not within a factor of 20 of being adequate for making correct decisions on which predictors are important.  See [this](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/hdata) for more information.

To fully expose the difficulty of the task, use the bootstrap or Bayesian modeling to compute uncertainty intervals for variable importance.  These confidence intervals for your situation will tell you that the data contain **no information** about the relative importance of variables, even if there were no collinearities.  With collinearities it is far worse.  For an example using the bootstrap see [this](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/validate#fig-val-rex).